# 12.04 LTS: fstab mount fails, but udisks mount works

Tags: fstab

I set up a dual boot setup on my netbook to try Ubuntu.  Since I liked it, I carved out an additional partition to use with Ubuntu.

I am able to successfully mount this partion by adding this command to Startup Applications

> /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/c1e4fe5a-df6b-4910-811d-a6f5d76d59c2

However, in the interest of learning, I tried to mount this partition through fstab instead, since it seemed that this was the more normal way. Here are all the lines from fstab that are not comments.  I added the last line.

> UUID=4c24d79e-fd82-45a7-91fc-787aff8ec4e1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
>
> UUID=9e15e92b-411d-443e-a3d4-584748010ba5 none            swap    sw              0       0
>
> UUID=c1e4fe5a-df6b-4910-811d-a6f5d76d59c2 /media/mountpoint auto auto,users,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 2

Before saving the fstab, I disabled my Startup Application command, rebooted, and confirmed that the new partition was not mounted.  I then saved fstab and did the

> sudo mount -a

but I got this error

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda3,
>
> ```
>   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>
>   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>
>   dmesg | tail  or so
> ```

I'd appreciate any advice on what I did wrong with my fstab update.

Comment: BTW you ONLY need to run the command to build / update fstab during something like a command line installation (archlinux for example). Just edit the file as you normally would any other file and the system will read fstab during boot on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the line

```
UUID=c1e4fe5a-df6b-4910-811d-a6f5d76d59c2 /media          ext4    defaults 0       1
```

in /etc/fstab instead of the one you have and reboot

you don't have to do anything else; the volume will be mounted in the folder /media as the system will read fstab automatically when you boot

Comment: Worked perfectly just as you wrote it.  Many thanks.